# Spring MVC development process - best practices

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, portlet, development-process

What is the right development process of Spring MVC / portlet-MVC application using JSPs as a view layer, when we don't take service/DAO layer in account - it is usually done already.

I mean, if I'm creating controller + JSP(s) at a time, I'm getting kinda lost in a while and everything seems a mess, I'm loosing the overall survey about the application design and requirements. But on the other way I can't imagine that I would create JSPs at first and then controllers or controllers at first and then JSPs.

Programming portlets is much more complicated and having this resolved seems important.

Note: Consider no development team (graphic designer + programmer), I'm doing all by myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start by declaring the most significant areas, within the entire portlet plugin I'm about to develop, from both technology and "business logic" point of view. I usually assign one controller for each such area.

```
HTML form          -  Controller - InternalResourceViewResolver   - JSP
Common rendering   -  Controller - InternalResourceViewResolver   - JSP
Ajax component     -  Controller - BeanNameViewResolver           - YUI + JSP + JSON
```

I like the iterative style of programming. Create the "skeleton" that it is acceptable to monetize it. And then I spend 2 times more time by making it fancier.